# execute php commands directly in the console instead exec command

Tags: php, docker, command

I am using PHPstorm and Docker (beginner) and have set up a runtime environment to run a Laravel project.

To enter a php command in the console I have to first, every time after composing the docker-compose.yml, enter the command `docker exec -it container-php bash`, then change to the "/app" directory to execute php commands. This is cumbersome. I wanted to know is there an easier way to execute commands without the `docker exec` command?
Is there any way to automate this so I can just enter the commands as usual under Xampp?

Maybe someone can give a tip?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can skip the docker exec -it and just run your command directly like so: `docker exec <container> "cd /app && <command here>"`

alternatively if you are running lots of different commands you could just use an alias: `alias inlaravel="docker exec container-php $1"` and use it like so: `inlaravel "echo hi"`.  You could also replace "inlaravel" with something much shorter to make it faster to type.

You can put this in your bash profile if you don't mind it being global, or if you want to keep it scoped to the project I would recommend using something like direnv.